# Testing wrapper.props shallow render is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, chai, enzyme

I want to test the following code:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <Connect />
    <FlatList
        data={[
            {key: "pp", title: "Privacy Policy"},
            {key: "tos", title: "Terms of Service"},
        ]}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
                <View
                    onPress={() => this.handleOnPress(item.key)}
                >
                    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }}
    />
</React.Fragment>
```

These are my tests:

```
it("should render a FlatList with 2 items", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <Menu
            />
        );
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
        expect(wrapper.props().data).toHaveLength(2);
    });
```

For some reason, it is failing and showing `.data` is undefined. I basically want to test that my flat list has 2 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, then it looks like you're trying to get the `.props()` of the `<Menu/>` (wrapper) , rather than the `<FlatList/>` which is a child of the wrapper.

By using the `.childAt` method, you should be able to resolve the problem with the following:

```
it("should render a FlatList with 2 items", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <Menu
        />
    );
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

    // expect(wrapper.props().data).toHaveLength(2);

    expect(
      wrapper // the wrapper of 'Menu'
      .childAt(1) // the second child of the 'Menu' which is the 'FlatList'
      .props() // the props of 'FlatList'
      .data // the data field of 'FlatList' props
    ).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

[Here is more information on the `.childAt()` method](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/childAt.html) - hope this helps